Struggle understanding number of Grafana Alerting evaluations
I have an alert where the pending period is 16 minutes and the evaluation interval is 5 minutes:

I would expect that only 4 evaluations are needed:

0th minute evaluation => Alert goes into pending.
5th minute evaluation => Alert stays pending.
10th minute evaluation => Alert stays pending.
15th minutes evaluation => Alert stays pending.
16th minute => Alert fires.

The official docs specify exactly this behaviour:

The rule stays in the “pending” state until the condition has been broken for the required amount of time - pending period.

It doesn't state, that an evaluation is needed AFTER the pending period when an Alert condition persists...
Why is it 5 evaluations instead of 4 here?
Is that behavior documented somewhere?

Maybe someone can add the tag alerting...
